# Ошибка в Opencart Undefined index: route in vqmod/vqcache

Tags: php, opencart

Помогите разобраться. Что не так с этими строками?

```
17: if (empty($current_path) || $current_path['route'] == 'common/home') {
                    $body_class = 'home';
                } else {
20: $body_class = explode('/', str_replace('product/', '', $current_path['route']));
```

> Notice: Undefined index: route in vqmod/vqcache/vq2-catalog_controller_common_header.php on line 17
>   Notice: Undefined index: route in vqmod/vqcache/vq2-catalog_controller_common_header.php on line 20

Comment: Сделайте вывод `var_dump($current_path);` перед 17 строкой и посмотрите, что за данные у вас там содержатся.

Comment: @Владимир Алексеев Я совершенно не знаю PHP, но на мой взгляд сообщение об ошибке предельно ясное: "Undefined index: route in vqmod/vqcache/vq2" Где вы здесь видите route?

Comment: @VladfromMoscow, если вы не видите тут `route`, это не значит, что его тут нет :P Я его в этом коде вижу.

Answer (score 1):

```
            В таком варианте выбивало ошибку
            if (empty($current_path) || $current_path['route'] == 'common/home') {
                $body_class = 'home';
            } else {
                $body_class = explode('/', str_replace('product/', '', $current_path['route']));
                unset($current_path['route']);
                if (isset($current_path['_route_'])) {
                    $body_class = array_merge($body_class, explode('/', str_replace('-', '_', $current_path['_route_'])));
                    unset($current_path['_route_']);
                } foreach ($current_path as $key => $value) {
                    $body_class[] = $key . "_" . $value;
                } 
                $body_class = 'page_' . implode(" page_", array_unique($body_class));
            }
            $body_class .= ' lang_' . $this->language->get('code');
            $this->data['body_class'] = $body_class;


            $this->load->model('tool/image');
```

Обернул весь блок в if (isset($this->request->get['route'])) { }
И ошибка пропала.